# How to make category selector like Zomato in the image below

Tags: android, github, android-library

Is there any github library for that and if yes then can you please help me and if not what is the other solution

I want same as "Home work other buttons"

[image: I want same as "Home work other buttons"]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do it by `Chips`

use `MaterialComponents`

https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

and use Materialtheme like ...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

your xml layout file

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <!-- Chips can be declared here, or added dynamically. -->

</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Comment: @Rattan Singh if it works, you can also upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Chips](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) component from Material Components.

The `Chip` used in your image is a Choice Chip and can be used like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Home"/>
```